# Service Stack Basic Auth Routes only accesible from localhost?

Tags: authentication, servicestack

I'm using service stacks basic auth plugin. When I access any of the auth routes it adds like /register, or /auth from the machine the service is running on (localhost) the routes work fine.

When I access the routes from one of my clients on another machine I get 401 not authorized errors on all of these routes.

I already have the Cors plugin enabled, and my non authentication routes are working fine from remote clients.

Is there something else that needs configured to allow  access to the auth routes to work from remote clients/ips?

Answer (score 1):

The response is always a 401 it appears if the authentication user or password is wrong or doesn't exist. With an existing user or password it is fine.